# How to get selected image file name from ImagePicker using Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, imagepicker

I am using ImagePicker with SwiftUI by UIImagePickerController. It can select an Image. But I want to know the original image file name also. Is there any way to do this?

I already tried this using following codes:

```
if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL {

  imagePicker.fileName = url.lastPathComponent

  imagePicker.fileType = url.pathExtension

}
```

But above code gives the temporary image file name.

Answer (score 2):

I tried but I couldn't get file name (url) from UIImage.

Following code solves the problem temporarily.

```
      if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as? URL {
            let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
            if let firstAsset = assets.firstObject,
            let firstResource = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: firstAsset).first {
                imagePicker.fileName = firstResource.originalFilename
            } else {
                imagePicker.fileName = "IMG_random_string"
            }
        } else {
            imagePicker.fileName = "IMG_random_string"
        }
```

But here referenceURL and fetchAssets are depreciated. I tried with PHPickerViewController, but again couldn't find how to get selected image file name from it.

Thanks! :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `originalImage` attribute if you need to access the picked `UIImage`:

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
   ...
}
```